# Type error if link.has_attr('href'): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to execute the following python code

```
import httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('http://www.nytimes.com')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print link['href']
```

Edit:
I changed the code to this

```
for link in BeautifulSoup(response).find_all('a', href=True):
    print link['href']
```

But still getting same error

I  am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/Documents/machinelearning/extract_links.py", line 8, in <module>
    if link.has_attr('href'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What is the reason for this error?
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is returning a bunch of values along with `None` in it.

You're better off using `find_all()` here, in my opinion:

```
for link in BeautifulSoup(response).find_all('a', href=True):
    print link['href']
```

The `href=True` will only find a tags with a `href` value, so you won't need your conditional.

Comment: @Haido, Same error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/Documents/machinelearning/extract_links.py", line 7, in <module>
    for link in BeautifulSoup(response).find_all('a', href=True):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @Haido, yes you are true

Comment: @karu Can't help you there I'm afraid :). But glad we resolved that :). So what `BeautifulSoup()` is doing is creating something empty. (i.e `None`)

Comment: @Haido  yes, :) Right. Problem exists still :)