# BeautifulSoup not working, getting NoneType error

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using the following code (Taken from [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup#1080472)):

```
import httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('http://www.nytimes.com')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print link['href']
```

However, I don't understand why I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EANUAMA\workspace\PatternExtractor\src\SourceCodeExtractor.py", line 13, in <module>
    if link.has_attr('href'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

BeautifulSoup 3.2.0
Python 2.7

**EDIT:**

I tried the solution available for the similar question([Type error if link.has_attr('href'): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424009/type-error-if-link-has-attrhref-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-callabl)), but it is giving me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EANUAMA\workspace\PatternExtractor\src\SourceCodeExtractor.py", line 12, in <module>
    for link in BeautifulSoup(response).find_all('a', href=True):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type error if link.has\_attr('href'): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424009/type-error-if-link-has-attrhref-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-callabl)

Comment: @DavidZemens the duplicate question has not been resolved. Please see the comments in that question.

Comment: The duplicate question has an accepted answer which identifies *why* you're getting the error. Consider some additional debugging, and use `try/except` as needed...

Comment: Also, have you tried the method proposed in that answer?

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes, see my edit. Moreover, if you will see the comments in the original question then you would come to know that the OP didn't get a solution. "@Haido yes, :) Right. Problem exists still :) – karu"

Comment: What, specifically do you not understand about `NoneType` is not callable? BS is returning a `NoneType`, and your code (which you have only shown the traceback for) is not handling this potential error in the response object.

Comment: I didn't get why there is `NoneType` being returned by BeautifulSoup, as response is not Null. Moreover, response has `a href` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all:

> `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer`

You are using [`BeautifulSoup` version 3](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/) which is *no longer maintained*. Switch to [`BeautifulSoup` version 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Install it via:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and change your import to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

---

Also:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\EANUAMA\workspace\PatternExtractor\src\SourceCodeExtractor.py", line 13, in 
>       if link.has_attr('href'):
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Here `link` is a `Tag` instance which does not have an `has_attr` method. This means that, remembering what a [dot notation means in `BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names), it would try to search for element `has_attr` inside the `link` element which results into nothing found. In other words, `link.has_attr` is `None` and obviously `None('href')` results into an error.

Instead, do:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a', href=True))
for link in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

---

FYI, here is a complete working code that I used to debug your problem (using `requests`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer


response = requests.get('http://www.nytimes.com').content
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a', href=True)).find_all("a", href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```