# Python regex: not able to get match in group

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am using the following regex:

```
<a\s*href\s*=\s*\\\s*"(.*?)\\.*?>(.*?)<\/a>
```

Its purpose is to fetch the href's value and links name.

If you will have a look at the following link then you can see that I have 3 groups (0,1,2):

- group(1) gives the href's value
- group(2) gives the links name.

https://regex101.com/r/eD8vN7/1

But when I use this regex in python I get the wrong output in group(1).

Input:

```
<a href=\"https://abc/asd/asd/ki.html\" class=\"wfid_temp560484 link\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"target-new: tab;\"  data-ajax=\"false\">scheduling_PFS</a>
```

Actual Output:

group1:

```
https://abc/asd/asd/ki.html\" class=\"wfid_temp560484 link\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"target-new: tab;\"  data-ajax=\"false\"
```

Expected Output:

group1:

```
https://abc/asd/asd/ki.html
```

**EDIT:**

The input string is very complex, it can have multiple tags following one another:

```
<a href=\"http://sewe518.lmweera.kolio.se:8001/dtr?jobid=6170286\" class=\"wfid_temp560484 link\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"target-new: tab;\"  data-ajax=\"false\">scheduling_PFS</a></td><td class=\"wfid_temp560509 tablecell\" style=\"color:green\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" colspan=\"1\" rowspan=\"1\" >13</td><td class=\"wfid_temp560531 tablecell\" style=\"color:brown\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" colspan=\"1\" rowspan=\"1\" >
```

Comment: Judging by your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733853/beautifulsoup-not-working-getting-nonetype-error), you're already using an actual HTML parser. What's with the regex? Why not let BeautifulSoup do its job?

Comment: @user2357112 My HTML is using Nitrogen, eg: `Nitrogen.$insert_after("page", ".wfid_panel", "<div class=\"wfid_temp560240 wfid_dtr_single_table panel\" style=\"float: left;\" ><table border=\"0\" class=\"wide wfid_temp560262 table\" ><tbody><tr class=\"wfid_temp560284 tablerow\" ><th class=\"wfid_temp560300 tableheader\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" colspan=\"6\" rowspan=\"1\" >Job: 6170286</th></tr>` that's why BeautifulSoup is not working. I guess Nitrogen is some Erlang library.

Comment: your rule seems wrong as you have only one `"`

Comment: try with: `<a\s*href\s*=\s*\\\s*"(.*?)"\\.*?>(.*?)<\/a>`

Comment: @pl-94 please have a look at the link that I have shared. It seems that the regex is correct.

Comment: @pl-94 your regex is not working.

Comment: `<a\s*href\s*=\s*\\\s*"(http:\/\/.*?)\:.*?>(.*?)<\/a>` ? Which library do you employ in Python? RE?

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/lBu5Mx)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
<a.+(http.*://[]\w/.]+.\w+):*.*\>(\w+)<\/a>
```

see [this](https://regex101.com/r/xJ7sZ7/2)

Comment: Not working, try this input string: `<a href=\"http://sewe518.lmweera.kolio.se:8001/dtr?jobid=6170286\" class=\"wfid_temp560484 link\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"target-new: tab;\"  data-ajax=\"false\">scheduling_PFS</a>`

Comment: thanks for your time!! But the input is little complex than what I mentioned earlier. Your regex does not work for such inputs. See the edit.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11481926)

Comment: @Zulan: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​How is this answer should be a comment?

Comment: @KevinGuan the question mark and the lack of explanation makes this look more like a comment than an answer. Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: @Zulan: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I think that the [*wrong answers, partial answers or wrong answers* shouldn't get deleted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563). This maybe is a bad answer, but we shouldn't (vote to) delete it, instead, comment and downvote (if needed).

Comment: @KevinGuan Maybe I am reading this differently, but the formulation "Can you try this?" is **asking** the OP to **attempt** a certain thing that may lead towards a solution, but maybe it doesn't. Therefore it is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one: `href=\\"(\S*)\\".*>(.*)</a>`

[link](https://regex101.com/r/wR2bG6/1)

Comment: The problem with your initial pattern is that white spaces are included into matches. Try to replace your (.*) with (\S) ( with capital S ) so it includes only non whites chars

Comment: Objection withdrawn; I didn't see that the link was a demonstration of the string.  In general, "can you try this" suggests that you haven't tested the item yourself.